# Can I use regular expressions in R to turn a list into a data frame, with each column containing similar character strings in it?

Tags: r, database, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a list of ~700 character strings in a vector, something like this:

```
list <- c("orange", "Orange", "Orange juice", "orange juice", "lemon drink", "Lemon", "lemonade", "apple pie", "Apple", "Apples", "Grapefruit", "grape fruit", "Grapefruit tea")
```

And I'd like to create a dataframe with each different variant in a separate column, like this:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(column1 = c("orange", "lemon drink", "apple pie", "grapefruit"),
                        column2 = c("Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "grape fruit"),
                        column3 = c("Orange juice", "lemonade", "Apples", "Grapefruit tea"),
                        column4 = c("orange juice", NA, NA, NA)
                        )
```

Is there a way of doing this using R, reducing manual work as much as possible? I'm a beginner with Regular Expressions, but I suspect this might be the way to go? If anyone can give me any pointers, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a distance method to group the words by its similarity (`soundex`), `split` the vector of words into a `list` and convert the `list` back to a data.frame by appending `NA`s at the end (if the `lengths` are different

```
library(phonics)
library(stringi)
lst1 <- split(list, soundex(list, maxCodeLen = 3, clean = FALSE))
df1 <- as.data.frame(stri_list2matrix(lst1, byrow = TRUE))
```

-output

```
> df1
           V1          V2             V3           V4
1   apple pie       Apple         Apples         <NA>
2  Grapefruit grape fruit Grapefruit tea         <NA>
3 lemon drink       Lemon       lemonade         <NA>
4      orange      Orange   Orange juice orange juice
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but got this message:                                                            
 "Warning: argument is not an atomic vector; coercing". I've tried to convert the list into a character using as.character before & after using the split function but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Specifically, the warning is generated from this function:                        
 stri_list2matrix(lst1, byrow = TRUE)

Comment: @Pigeoncity22 is it based on the same example you posted?  I didn't get any warnings

Comment: Sorry! I realised that my original list was actually a dataframe, so I converted that to a vector and it was fine. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried it with refinedSoundex as well, which works slightly better for me :)